# How to scroll beyond the 'bottom' of a div

Tags: javascript, window, scroll

I have two divs, left contains a treeview which calls a javascript function to scroll the div to the right to some content.

The scroll works fine for the most part except near the bottom of the content div.  With no more scrolling available you cant make those elements scroll up to the top of the div.

One option is to programmatically increase the height of the content div so that it has at least a clientHeight more height - so elements that would have been at the bottom can be scrolled past that point, to the top.

Does anyone have a simpler solution? Because when I add height to the content div, it extends beyond the area I want that div within.

Comment: you hould make exaple on jsfiddle.net or at least show some code. Its verz hard to help you without it...

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the right view inside div that has 'overflow: hidden' style? In that way you can have what ever height div inside it and it doesn't overflow.